# How do I make writing Bold using Python

Tags: python, lua, roblox

I am making a python document for a group. I have on a website called Roblox <*www.roblox.com*> and I teach them ROBLOX Lua which is used to make games on ROBLOX. I am trying to make the writing go **bold** but the way I found isn't working and I'm hoping you can help me out.

```
print ("In ROBLOX Studio there are", color.BOLD, "scripts.", color.END)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a python document"? Is it a bare .py file store on your website? Is it an HTML document with snippets of code? Are you executing `print` calls and trying to get bold formatting in the result - from a server with CGI, or locally in a console, or...?

Comment: @tigerhawkT3 it is a IDLE document on my hard drive.

Comment: That doesn't convey any meaning.

Comment: Is it bare HTML?  Try `print "In ROBLOX Studio there are <b>scripts</b>."`

Comment: I am using python IDLE its not on a website its the downloadable software from http://www.python.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
print ('\033[1m' + 'In ROBLOX Studio there are' + '\033[1m')
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work the output for that is [1mIn ROBLOX Studio there are[1m

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? And where do you want to display this message? In a console?

Comment: I am using 3.3 version and it comes up in red writing on the shell

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what error shows up? Like the red one.